# The type org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext cannot be resolved

Tags: spring

```
 package test;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

 import config.StudentConfig;
 import model.Student;

 public class StudentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext Context= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(StudentConfig.class);
        Student obj=(Student)Context.getBean("student");

    }
}
```

Eclipse errors out saying, "The type org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **org.springframework.context** and **org.springframework.context.support** dependencies (jar) to your spring project. The class **org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext** is available in these jars.

Comment: Thank you.It helped

Comment: I am glad it helped